# Flatten a list of elements in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My data-structure is:

```
ds = [{
    "name": "groupA",
    "subGroups": [123,456]
},
{
    "name": "groupB",
    "subGroups": ['aaa', 'bbb' , 'ccc']
}]
```

This gives the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ds)

    name    subGroups
0   groupA  [123, 456]
1   groupB  [aaa, bbb, ccc]
```

I want:

```
    name    subGroupsFlattend
0   groupA  123
1   groupA  456
2   groupB  aaa
3   groupB  bbb
4   groupB  ccc
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix your output by following :

```
pd.DataFrame({'name':df.name.repeat(df.subGroups.str.len()),'subGroup':df.subGroups.sum()})
Out[364]: 
     name subGroup
0  groupA      123
0  groupA      456
1  groupB      aaa
1  groupB      bbb
1  groupB      ccc
```

Comment: @daiyue flatten the list

Comment: what if the dtype of the series is not string, and couldn't use `str.len`, what should I use?

Comment: @daiyue what you mean is not string , in this question it is not string but object (list)

Answer (score 10):

Use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = df.explode('subGroups')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(ds,  ['subGroups'], 'name').rename(columns={0:'subGroupsFlattend'})
print (df)
  subGroupsFlattend    name
0               123  groupA
1               456  groupA
2               aaa  groupB
3               bbb  groupB
4               ccc  groupB
```

Alternative solution with flattening dictionaries:

```
L = [y for x in ds for y in zip(x["subGroups"], [x["name"]] * len(x["subGroups"]))]
print (L)
[(123, 'groupA'), (456, 'groupA'), ('aaa', 'groupB'), ('bbb', 'groupB'), ('ccc', 'groupB')]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['subGroupsFlattend','name'])
print (df)
  subGroupsFlattend    name
0               123  groupA
1               456  groupA
2               aaa  groupB
3               bbb  groupB
4               ccc  groupB
```

EDIT:

```
from itertools import chain
df = pd.DataFrame(ds)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'subGroups' : list(chain.from_iterable(df['subGroups'].tolist())), 
    'name' : df['name'].values.repeat(df['subGroups'].str.len())
})
print (df1)
     name subGroups
0  groupA       123
1  groupA       456
2  groupB       aaa
3  groupB       bbb
4  groupB       ccc
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  What if I already have the DataFrame as described in question and I have no access to the DataStructure.  Should I make the DataFrame into DataStructure first?

Comment: @MoreThanFive - If already `DataFrame` is created, then use edited answer with flatenning `list`s.

Answer (score 0):

YOBEN_S solution, but much more efficient for big dataframes.

```
from itertools import chain
pd.DataFrame({'name':df.name.repeat(df.subGroups.str.len()),
              'subGroup':list(chain.from_iterable(df.subGroups.to_list()))})
```