# pandas how to flatten a list in a column while keeping list ids for each element

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`,

```
 A                                                          id
[ObjectId('5abb6fab81c0')]                                  0
[ObjectId('5abb6fab81c3'),ObjectId('5abb6fab81c4')]         1
[ObjectId('5abb6fab81c2'),ObjectId('5abb6fab81c1')]         2
```

I like to flatten each list in `A`, and assign its corresponding `id` to each element in the list like,

```
 A                               id
 ObjectId('5abb6fab81c0')        0
 ObjectId('5abb6fab81c3')        1
 ObjectId('5abb6fab81c4')        1
 ObjectId('5abb6fab81c2')        2
 ObjectId('5abb6fab81c1')        2
```

Comment: daiyue, out of curiosity I tested my code against @Wen's code, and posted the results as an edit to my answer. Turns out that each of our codes is more optimized depending on your input data, and one may run significantly faster than the other!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the comment is coming from this question ? you can using my [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49452192/7964527) or this one

```
df.set_index('id').A.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().drop('level_1',1)
Out[497]: 
   id    0
0   0  1.0
1   1  2.0
2   1  3.0
3   1  4.0
4   2  5.0
5   2  6.0
```

Or

```
pd.DataFrame({'id':df.id.repeat(df.A.str.len()),'A':df.A.sum()})
Out[498]: 
   A  id
0  1   0
1  2   1
1  3   1
1  4   1
2  5   2
2  6   2
```

Comment: in my case, `df.A` is not a string column, so I got `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

Comment: @daiyue then can you show what type of column A is ?

Comment: @daiyue so [2,3,4] this is int ? Is the sample you show to us can reproduced your problem ?

Comment: have edited my op, was oversimplified my example, I also tried solution 2, but got error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ObjectId' and 'ObjectId'`, but solution 1 works perfectly.

Comment: This is the magic I imagined existed when writing my answer. Nice work.

Comment: @daiyue since it still list in cell , you can always using str.len to get the length of list for each cell

Comment: Wen, out of curiosity I tested my code against yours, and posted the results as an edit to my answer. Turns out that each of our codes is more optimized depending on the input data, and one may run significantly faster than the other!

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't the most elegant solution, but it works. The idea here is to loop through `df` (which is why this is likely an inefficient solution), and then loop through each list in column `A`, appending each item and the `id` to new lists. Those two new lists are then turned into a new DataFrame.

```
a_list = []
id_list = []
for index, a, i in df.itertuples():
    for item in a:
        a_list.append(item)
        id_list.append(i)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(alist, idlist)), columns=['A', 'id'])
```

As I said, inelegant, but it gets the job done. There's probably at least one better way to optimize this, but hopefully it gets you moving forward.

### EDIT (April 2, 2018)

I had the thought to run a timing comparison between mine and Wen's code, simply out of curiosity. The two variables are the length of column `A`, and the length of the list entries in column `A`. I ran a bunch of test cases, iterating by orders of magnitude each time. For example, I started with `A` length = 10 and ran through to 1,000,000, at each step iterating through randomized `A` entry list lengths of 1-10, 1-100 ... 1-1,000,000. I found the following:

- **Overall, my code is noticeably faster (*especially* at increasing `A` lengths) as long as the list lengths are less than ~1,000.** As soon as the randomized list length hits the ~1,000 barrier, Wen's code takes over in speed. This was a huge surprise to me! I fully expected my code to lose every time.
- **Length of column `A` generally doesn't matter** - it simply increases the overall execution time linearly. The only case in which it changed the results was for `A` length = 10. In that case, no matter the list length, my code ran faster (also strange to me).

**Conclusion**: If the list entries in `A` are on the order of a few hundred elements (or less) long, my code is the way to go. But if you're working with huge data sets, use Wen's! Also worth noting that as you hit the 1,000,000 barrier, both methods slow down drastically. I'm using a fairly powerful computer, and each were taking minutes by the end (it actually crashed on the `A` length = 1,000,000 and list length = 1,000,000 case).

Answer (score 0):

Flattening and unflattening can be done using this function

```
def flatten(df, col):
    col_flat = pd.DataFrame([[i, x] for i, y in df[col].apply(list).iteritems() for x in y], columns=['I', col])
    col_flat = col_flat.set_index('I')
    df = df.drop(col, 1)
    df = df.merge(col_flat, left_index=True, right_index=True)

    return df
```

Unflattening:

```
def unflatten(flat_df, col):
    flat_df.groupby(level=0).agg({**{c:'first' for c in flat_df.columns}, col: list})
```

After unflattening we get the same dataframe except column order:

```
(df.sort_index(axis=1) == unflatten(flatten(df)).sort_index(axis=1)).all().all()
>> True
```

To create unique index you can call `reset_index` after flattening